# Ajax UpdatePanel placed in a UserControl in ContentPlaceHolder of MaterPage is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a MasterPage in which i have declared the ScriptManager. In the ContentPLaceHolder I have a UserControl in which I have ajax UpdatePanel. The Partial postbacks are not working on the button inside the updatepanel.

On my usercontrol

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="before"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ScriptManager On MasterPager

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: It works fine so it is probably another issue. See stackoverflow.com/questions/39051939/update-panel-does-not-respond-to-button-event

Comment: when I use the above code, the function calls but partial postback does not take place